# how to post multiple table rows as a two-dimensional array

Tags: laravel, object, post

I'm trying out Laravel and have been trying to post multiple rows as a two-dimensional array to the controller.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
 <div class="container">  
<h3>Declaratie formulier voor: {{ $project->name }}</h3>
<form method="POST" id="declaration-form" action="{{ url('SaveDeclaration') }}" role="form" style="display: block;">
    @csrf
<table>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="{{ $project->id }}" name="project_id" value="{{ $project->id }}">
    @foreach($articles as $article)
    <tr class="form-group col-md-13">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="{{ $project->id }}" name="article_id" value=" {{ $article->id }}">       
            <td><label for="{{ $article->id }}">{{ $article->description }}</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{ $article->id }}" name="price" placeholder="Vul in"></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Declareer</button>
</form>
</div>
@endsection
```

I can't seem to find an answer on how to post a multi-dimensional array (every row) from the view. Is there any way to show Laravel that these are supposed to be placed inside a multi-dimensional array? I'm just getting a single row back when i `$data->post();` ask for the data.

Comment: Use [] in your input names.

Comment: Yeah, that works. Thanks! Will be looking for a more robust way to make an actual multi-dimensional array.

Comment: You can use [index] if you need.

Comment: How do you mean??

Comment: Example articles[0][name] and articles[1][name] will give you an array with two array each containing a name key.

Comment: Ahh, yeah okay, great!